# No module named 'PIL' in Python - : No module named 'sqlalchemy' ERROR. after install the modules

Tags: python, module

I got this problem and I have read some solution about installing the modules before using it, and I did that, I install the modules, but yet this message appear to me " No module named 'PIL' in Python".

```
from PIL import ImageTk
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
```

Comment: Where are you running your code?

Comment: pycharm,  python 3, win 10

Comment: pycharm creates a venv by default, so make sure you installed those libraries there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ryuga is likely correct. The python interpreter you installed those modules/packages to is likely the system default and not the one PyCharm is using to run your code.

Go to File -> Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter to see which your project is using and make changes accordingly.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked fine to me, the packages where not found there so I click the PLUS sign (+) and search for them then installed them successfully.

Thank you @JerodG.

Comment: do I have to do this in every new project?

how to make it automatically added there?